# Regex accepts * without specifing it in the pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

Developing a JavaScript regex, we found out some weird behaviour.

For following pattern: `[\'-=]`

The character `*` is accepted. (`'`, `-`, `=` are also accepted but this is expected.)

We can replace '=' by any character. If we change pattern characters order, it does not work anymore.

Anyone got an idea about this?

Comment: escape the `-` character too ... so `\-`

Answer (score 10):

The "-" character in the middle of the pattern is what's causing your problem.  The "-" character is special inside character groups like that, and it means "all the characters between".  Thus, "'-=" means "all characters from "'" through "=".  It happens that "*" is in that range.

To fix it, re-order the list of characters so that the "-" is at the end, or else quote it with a backslash.

Answer (score 5):

because in this case `-` means range. In ASCII table `*` is between `'` and `=`.Your pattenr will also match all other characters between `'` and `=` (e.g digits). You can find all ASCII characters [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).
If you want to match `'` `=` or `-` you should escape minus sign. Use this pattern: `[\'\-=]`

Answer (score 4):

the - char has a special meaning in char sequences in regexp.

it creates a range

[\'-=] means accept \ and all chars between ' and  =

to specify - in a char sequence, you have to put it at the end

[\'=-] will do what tou expect.

Comment: Actually, it just means accept all chars between `'` and `=` - which doesn't include "\". In this case, the backslash will be interpreted as an escape character, even though it makes little sense to escape `'`. Only GNU and POSIX flavors will use the backslash as a literal backslash. In everything else, including javascript, `['=-]` will do the same as `[\'=-]`.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's because you have to escape the '-', otherwise it's range (like [A-Z]).

Answer (score 4):

The `-` character is used to specify a range in a set, for example `[a-z]`. Your set matches any character from `'` to `=`, i.e. all the characters `'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=`.

You have to escape the `-` to use it literally:

```
[\'\-=]
```